# setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)) does not convert the calendar to pure GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, offset, type-conversion, gregorian-calendar, dateadd

```
GregorianCalendar test= new GregorianCalendar();
BigDecimal coef=new BigDecimal(-2113480800);
test.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
test.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
test.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
test.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1600);
test.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-583657);
System.out.println((test.getTime()));

// I should get Jan 1 0003 but i get 03 jan 0003 OFFSET of 2
```

Comment: Why have you created a `BigDecimal` that you then ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar you're using is fine - you just need to remember that a `Date` *only* stores an instant in time. It doesn't remember a calendar, time zone or text format.

The `Date` value you've got is correct - it has an epoch millis of -62072462953058, which corresponds to 0003-01-01T17:10:46Z (at least for me - depends on time at which you run the code) in a system which doesn't use the Gregorian change.

However, `Date.toString()` formats that instant as if there *was* a Gregorian change, leading to the two day offset.

You can see this by using Java 8's `Instant` instead:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        GregorianCalendar test = new GregorianCalendar();
        test.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
        test.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        test.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        test.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1600);
        test.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-583657);
        Date date = test.getTime();
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

Output (at the moment, in London):

```
Wed Jan 03 17:15:26 GMT 3
0003-01-01T17:15:26.913Z
```

The two values represent the same point in time, but the `Instant` conversion to string doesn't perform a Julian/Gregorian cutover, whereas `Date` does.

Comment: what i would like to do is add certain time from an ANSI/UNIXTIMESTAMP format to ISO format considering their origin. the input date that i take is converted to UNIXTIMESTAMP/ANSI and I have to convert it back to the same date. TimeZone and currentTime can be ignored. I just need to add and subtract time either in seconds or days to some ORIGIN.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "ANSI/UNIXTIMESTAMP format" - or how that relates to the problem you've shown. I suggest you ask a new question that demonstrates this.

Comment: What I was simply trying to do above is that I wanted to add -583657 days to the origin 1600/12/31, the time format which considers 00:00:00 Jan 1, 1601 as day 1. So, -583657 would mean the date after adding -583657days to the origin above. But, using, GeorgianCalendar I get Jan 3, 0003 00:00:00. But, the actual date is Jan 1, 0003 00:00:00. The Gregorian calendar in java is a hybrid with Julian date, and I get certain offsets while subtracting number of days even if I set setGregorianChange() as above according to the API to convert to proleptic one. Could you suggest me a better approach?

Comment: @1234jkl: But your code doesn't do any conversion to ISO format. If you create another `SimpleDateFormat` using the same Gregorian-only calendar, I'd expect you to get the right results. But you never asked about that in your question - hence my suggestion that you ask a new question with the details of what you're *really* trying to do. That shouldn't be in the comments, and you shouldn't change the question for it either.